# String comparison mysteriously failing

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare two strings in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175390/how-do-i-compare-two-strings-in-perl)

Why does this script always return "You won"?

```
print "Choose heads or tails :\n";
$answer = <STDIN>;
chomp $answer;

if( $answer == "heads" ) {
    print "You won\n";
}
else {
    print "Moron! You lost.\n"
}
```

And what should be the correct code for the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175390/how-do-i-compare-two-strings-in-perl

Comment: And `use strict;`. They would have alerted you to that problem (Argument "heads" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)) and that you haven't declared your `$answer` variable before using it.

Comment: "Argument "heads" isn't numeric" would have come from `warnings`, not `strict`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

String comparation in Perl uses `eq` instead of `==`. Try:

```
if ($answer eq "heads")
```

If you are comparing numbers you use `==`.

Read more about it in a post at [perlmonks.](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=276020)

When learning Perl I suggest you start your scripts with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. That way you will get a warning for this kind of operation. And it will also help you with misspelled variables.

Comment: I used strict for other programs. In one, I took an input from user in the following format : '$n=<STDIN>;' and I got an error like this - 'It requires explicit package name.' Got the same error for loop variables also. Can you elaborate on the same?

Comment: Declare variables using `my` before them. I.e. `my $n;` or `my $n = <STDIN>;`

Comment: @Exorcist - what resources are you using to learn Perl? Some are pretty old and out of date.

Comment: @Exorcist, we keep a list of [good tutorials](http://perl-tutorial.org/) (and bad) to help newcomers learn the right way. Perl has been around a long time and many of the old (bad) tutorials still exist out on the interwebs. Pick  one of these good ones and continue learning. :-)

Comment: @Qiau-Whats the use of `my`? @DVK-I am using Strawberry Perl. @Joel Berger- Can you please look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546239/learning-perl-for-web-designing