# String compare in Perl with "eq" vs "=="

Tags: string, perl

I am (a complete Perl newbie) doing string compare in an `if` statement:

If I do following:

```
if ($str1 == "taste" && $str2 == "waste") { }
```

I see the correct result (i.e. if the condition matches, it evaluates the "then" block). But I see these warnings:

> Argument "taste" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at line number x. 
>   Argument "waste" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at line number x.

But if I do:

```
if ($str1 eq "taste" && $str2 eq "waste") { }
```

Even if the if condition is satisfied, it doesn't evaluate the "then" block.

Here, `$str1` is `taste` and `$str2` is `waste`.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Please post a self-contained example.  Without knowing what `$str1` and `$str2` are, we can't tell you why control is reaching more code we don't see.  To your question, `eq` compares scalars lexicographically so is useful here, while `==` compares numerically so won't meaningfully compare anything to `"taste"`.

Comment: @hari Post the exact code where the variables are initialized.  If possible, post the complete function or script.

Comment: It's not the correct result if the "then" block is evaluated even when the condition is false.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

First, **eq** is for comparing strings; **==** is for comparing numbers.

> Even if the "if" condition is satisfied, it doesn't evaluate the "then" block.

I think your problem is that your variables don't contain what you think they do. I think your `$str1` or `$str2` contains something like "taste\n" or so. Check them by printing before your **if**: `print "str1='$str1'\n";`.

The trailing newline can be removed with the `chomp($str1);` function.

Comment: How do I remove trailing newline if present before comparing?

Comment: @hari use `chomp`. See `perldoc -f chomp`.

Comment: yes, $str1 has "\n" at the end but using chomp is not helping. If I do: if( $str1 eq "taste\n") it works.

Comment: Damn, I also had a carriage return. This is what I needed: $str1 =~ s/\r|\n//g; What a rookie mistake.

Comment: @hari: This is a bit late, but if you have a `\r` character in your string I have to wonder how it got there. Windows uses `'\r\n` to mark the end of a line, but if you read from a text file *in text mode* you'll just get the `'\n`. Perhaps you're reading a Windows-formatted text file on a Unix or Cygwin system?

Answer (score 35):

`==` does a numeric comparison: it converts both arguments to a number and then compares them.  As long as `$str1` and `$str2` both evaluate to 0 as numbers, the condition will be satisfied.

`eq` does a string comparison: the two arguments must match lexically (case-sensitive) for the condition to be satisfied.

```
"foo" == "bar";   # True, both strings evaluate to 0.
"foo" eq "bar";   # False, the strings are not equivalent.
"Foo" eq "foo";   # False, the F characters are different cases.
"foo" eq "foo";   # True, both strings match exactly.
```

Comment: "2foo" == "3bar"; #False, the strings evaluates to respectively 2 and 3

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. A more interesting example would have been `"2foo" == "2bar"`, which would be true. Your example producing false is unsurprising and doesn't really illustrate the difference between the operators because those strings won't compare as equal with *any* operator.

Comment: The idea behind the example was to draw the parallel with "foo"=="bar" which is true, while with "2foo"=="3bar" is not

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to chomp the `$str1` and `$str2`?

I found a similar issue with using (another) `$str1` eq 'Y' and it only went away when I first did:

```
chomp($str1);
if ($str1 eq 'Y') {
....
}
```

works after that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This helped me! :) It's good to know the function chomp does not return the result, but just change the string itself.

Answer (score -6):

Maybe the condition you are using is incorrect:

```
$str1 == "taste" && $str2 == "waste"
```

The program will enter into `THEN` part only when both of the stated conditions are true.

You can try with `$str1 == "taste" || $str2 == "waste"`. This will execute the `THEN` part if anyone of the above conditions are true.