# Perl simple comparison == vs eq

Tags: perl

On the accepted answer for 
[String compare in Perl with "eq" vs "=="](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046669/perl-string-compare-with-eq-vs)

it says that `First, eq is for comparing strings; == is for comparing numbers.`

"== does a numeric comparison: it converts both arguments to a number and then compares them."
"eq does a string comparison: the two arguments must match lexically (case-sensitive)"

You can ONLY use eq for comparing strings but
both eq AND == works for comparing numbers

numbers are subset of strings so i just dont understand why you would ever use ==

Is there a reason why you would want to use == for comparing numeric values over just using eq for all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here is an example of why you might want `==`:](http://ideone.com/5aVujw)

```
$a = "3.0";
print "eq" if $a eq "3"; # this will not print
print "==" if $a == 3;   # this will print
```

3.0 is numerically equal to 3, so if you want them to be equal, use `==`.  If you want to do string comparisons, then `"3.0"` is not equal to "3", so in this case you would use `eq`.  Finally, `==` is a cheaper operation than `eq`.

Comment: ah yes. makes sense. didnt think about that particular instance.

Answer (score 4):

String comparisons are just plain different, especially with numbers.

```
@s_num=sort {$a <=> $b} (20,100,3);   # uses explicit numeric comparison
print "@s_num\n";                     # prints 3 20 100, like we expect

@s_char=sort (20,100,3);              # uses implicit string comparison
print "@s_char\n";                    # prints 100 20 3, not so good.
```

-Tom Williams