# How to compare strings case-sensitively?

Tags: string, perl

The `name` variable may contain 2 words: `template` or `TEMPLATE`. Comparing both words (`template` and `TEMPLATE`) to "template" string gives `TRUE`. For example, the code:

```
...
@name = split(/_/,$f,2);
print("$name[0]");
if ("$name[0]" == "template"){
    print ("\n lowercase \n"); 
} elsif ("$name[0]" == "TEMPLATE") {
    print ("\n UPPERCASE \n");
}
```

Results:

```
template

lowercase

TEMPLATE

lowercase
```

How to compare strings case-sensitively? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Halona *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`! And compare strings with `eq`, not `==`.

Comment: Thank you, Biffen, it has solved the problem :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [perl string compare with "eq" vs "=="](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046669/perl-string-compare-with-eq-vs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In perl, the `==` operator is used to make numeric comparisons, while the `eq` operator is used to make string comparisons.

If `$name[0]` contains `TEMPLATE` then this:

```
($name[0] == "template")
```

is equivalent to comparing `0` with `0`, since a string containing non-numeric data will be co-erced to `0` in a numeric context.

If you run it with warnings (`use warnings;` at the top of the script) you will see warnings about that.

If you want a case sensitive comparison it is enough to use:

```
($name[0] eq "template")
```

As a side issue there is no need to write the LHS as `"$name[0]"` as you have done.

Comment: Thank you hamic. Can you please explain what is "LHS"? I could not translate it..

Comment: LHS = Left hand side, I mean, you do not need the quotes around the variable. The quotes would only be needed if you wanted to insert the variable into some other text.