# If in Perl doesn't work. Did I made a mistake?

Tags: perl

I began learning Perl yesterday. I have written this code:

```
print "Please type in your password.\n";
print "Password: ";
chomp($password = <>);
if ($password == "admin")
{
 print "Password is correct!";
}
else
{
 print "Password is incorrect!";
}
```

When I write "admin" it tells me that the password is correct but when I write every other password it tells me the same thing. It's like the if doesn't execute. What can I do?

Comment: **Always** use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!!

Answer (score 5):

The Comparison Operator "==" is used to compare numbers whereas the operator "eq" is used to compare strings.

Answer (score 4):

To compare strings the `eq` operator is used. I made this mistake often, too.

```
…
if ($password eq "admin")
…
```

If you are using the `==` operator on strings, a number contained in the string is converted: `foo` goes to zero, `2foo` goes to `2`

Comment: Can you explain how the strings are being cast with the `==` operator such that they're equal? I would expect them to be compared by length with that operator, but that's obviously not the case.

Comment: Strings evaluate to the number zero always. Note "2foo" would fail. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14046696

Comment: Oh, thanks! I was mixing the string->number coercion with vector->number coercion. I've been on Perl 6 for a while, so I've forgotten the implicit details, since everything is more explicit in the next generation.

Comment: Thanks in advance for accepting my answer :)

Comment: It's not my question--I was trying to write an answer myself before you did, but I got stuck in explaining why the problem occurs. (Hence, my question to you.) Why don't you add that to your main answer above? That way you can not only correct, but teach.

Comment: @xanoetux - Strings do **not** always evaluate numerically to 0. A string beginning with a number (such as your "2foo" example) evaluates as the number it begins with: `perl -E 'say "2foo" + 0'` prints `2`, not `0`, and `perl -E 'say "foo" == "2foo" ? "equal" : "not equal"'` says `not equal`.

Comment: (My preceding comment is in reference to your comment which incorrectly states "Strings evaluate to the number zero always."  The actual answer has it right.)

Comment: Yes, I saw that too. But I cannot correct it now. As you said, the answer is clear

Answer (score 2):

Perl uses eq instead of == for string comparison.

Change

```
if ($password == "admin")
{
     print "Password is correct!";
}
```

To

```
if ($password eq "admin")
{
     print "Password is correct!";
}
```