# != operator not working

Tags: perl

I have the below if statement, the '!=' isn't working. The second if statement in this line of code will not work, can someone tell me why?

```
    if ($line =~ $search) {
        print "$line <br> <br>";     
    }
}
if ($line != $search) { #This if statement will not work
    print "word is not in file";
}
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  Have you used Data::Dumper or similar module to dump both vars to see what they contain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare two strings in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175390/how-do-i-compare-two-strings-in-perl)

Comment: The opposite of `if ($line =~ $search)` is `else ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The == and != operators compare the operands as numbers. The operators for string comparisons are `eq` and `ne`.

Reference: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you are looking for the opposite of =~,

you do not want ne or eq, but !~ as in

```
if ( $line !~ $search )
```

Also, beware of special ( for regex ) characters in $search.

[perl regex doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)