# Failing if statement

Tags: json, perl

Ok so I have this line of code that I cant figure out and if someone could help me with it that would be great. I am making a geo-location perl script as part of my project.

Here is the line of code

```
$isps = $info->{'isp'};

if ($isps = "Time Warner Cable")
 {

  print "Isp found, go to $website for more information\n";       
}

if ($isps = "Google") {

    print "Isp found, go to $website for more information\n";       
} else {

    print "No ISP located! No way of Contact via this terminal!";
}
```

Ok so basically I am trying to make the if statement read the JSON code and make it print certain text if the specific name is listed. I am adding more ISPs to the file but just those two for example for now.

If anyone could help me with this line of code, because I seriously cant figure it out.

Comment: What is the problem _exactly_?

Comment: I thought OP was showing pseudo-code of some sort, so voted to close for that reason, but this should be closed either as a duplicate of [How do I compare two strings in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1175390/100754) or as a typo. It would be great if someone can figure out a decent title. This has nothing to do with JSON, but I can't think of a decent, descriptive title.

Comment: @SinanÜnür I had just voted to close as typographical error, not reproducable (etc)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include details of what exactly is wrong with your approach.

Comment: @SinanÜnür  I removed that "JSON" from the title, at least for now

Comment: Please **always** add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to your code, especially if you are a newbie. It would have shown `Found = in conditional, should be == at ./t.pl line 11.` If you'd then change that to `==` (which is still wrong, but a bit better), it says `Argument "bar" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./t.pl line 11.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=` is the assignment operator. You want the string comparison operator `eq` instead.

In this line you are assigning the string `"Time Warner Cable"` to the `$isps` variable. Then the `if`-conditional sees the string and interprets it as true. The same for the next conditional.

```
if ($isps = "Time Warner Cable")
```

Instead, you want:

```
my $isps = $info->{'isp'};

if ($isps eq "Time Warner Cable") {
    print "Isp found, go to $website for more information\n";       
}
elsif ($isps eq "Google") {
    print "Isp found, go to $website for more information\n";       
} else {
    print "No ISP located! No way of Contact via this terminal!\n";
}
```

Comment: Probably worth noting - `use strict;` `use warnings;` tells you about this. `Found = in conditional, should be ==`

Answer (score 1):

You should update your question to tell us what's going wrong with your current code.

One major problem is that `=` is the assignment operator. To compare strings for equality, use the `eq` operator:

```
if ($isps eq "Time Warner Cable") # ...
```

(The `==` operator performs numeric comparison.)

For more information, `perldoc perlop`, available online [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Kinda knew to perl itself. I didnt realize it would be that easy. Thank you so much! Ill learn from my mistakes.